# How to find the largest range from a series of numbers using R?

Tags: r, range

I have a data set where length and age correspond with individual items (ID #), there are 4 different items, you can see on the data set below.

> range(dataset$length)

gives me the overall range of the length for all items. But I need to compare ranges to determine which item (ID #) has the largest range in length relative to the other 3.

```
 length age  ID #
3.5      5    1
7       10    1
10      15    1
4        5    2
8       10    2
13      15    2
3       5     3
7       10    3
9       15    3
4       5     4
5       10    4
7       15    4
```

Comment: see, e.g., `aggregate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
mins <- tapply(df$length, df$ID, min)
maxs <- tapply(df$length, df$ID, max)
unique( df$ID)[which.max(maxs-mins)]
```

Comment: >max(maxs-mins,na.rm=T) gives me the value of the greatest range, but how do I get it to tell me which ID that value corresponds with?

Comment: `which.max(maxs-mins)` gives you the index of the ID

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the differences in ranges:

```
lapply( with(dat, tapply(length, ID, range)), diff)
```

And you can wrap which.max around htat list to give you the ID associated with the largest value:

```
which.max( lapply( with(dat, tapply(length, ID, range)), diff) )
2 
2
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting "Error:unexpected symbol in "1apply""

Comment: Did you replace my `dat` with your `dataset`?

Comment: Yes, does it need to have na.rm=T in that statement if I have NA values?

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` in `dplyr` may be helpful:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(ID_range = n())
```

The above code is equivalent to the following (it's just written with `%>%`):

```
library(dplyr)

dataset <- group_by(dataset, ID)
summarize(dataset, ID_range = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach which doesn't use `dplyr`, though perhaps less elegant, is the `which` function.

```
range(dataset$length[which(dat$id == 1)])
range(dataset$length[which(dat$id == 2)])
range(dataset$length[which(dat$id == 3)])
range(dataset$length[which(dat$id == 4)])
```

You could also make a function that gives you the actual range (the difference between the max and the means) and use `lapply` to show you the IDs paired with their ranges.

```
largest_range <- function(id){
    rbind(id, 
    (max(data$length[which(data$id == id)]) - 
        min(data$length[which(data$id == id)])))
}

lapply(X = unique(data$id), FUN = largest_range)
```